# Liferay 7 cannot add or edit page,portlet and sites

Tags: java, liferay-7

I installed Liferay on my server, and i get problem of not being able to add, update the site, page, and portlet. Only in View mode.

Just FYI i'm using:

- Liferay 7.0 CE GA6
- Linux OS v 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
- Architecture : amd64
- JAVA 1.8.0

The main page of my liferay only displays the *Hello World portlet*, and *the navigation portlet* and *the configure page* displaying message:

> This portlet has been undeployed. Please redeploy it or remove it from
>   the page.

[image]

I have read some literature, saying that my liferay bundle is corrupted.

I already downloaded bundle liferay with `wget` or drag and drop bundle.zip via FTP. But always get the same result.

Resulting errors in `tail -f ../logs/catalina.out` :

**When starting liferay :**

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.portletbridge.portlet.GUIDException: error - failure to instantiate GUIDGeneratorjava.net.UnknownHostException: portal: portal: Name or service not known
---
ERROR [localhost-startStop-1][com_liferay_portal_osgi_web_portlet_tracker:97] [com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.portlet.tracker.internal.PortletTracker(22)] The activate method has thrown an exception
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.portletbridge.portlet.PortletBridgePortlet.createViewPortlet(PortletBridgePortlet.java:219)
```

**When access *navigation portlet* or *the configure page*:**

```
ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-6][BaseJSPPortletConfigurationIcon:59] Unable to include JSP /configuration/icon/copy_applications.jsp
ERROR [localhost-startStop-1][com_liferay_portal_osgi_web_portlet_tracker:97] [com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.portlet.tracker.internal.PortletTracker(22)] The activate method has thrown an exception
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.jsp.configuration.icon.copy_005fapplications_jsp._jspService(copy_005fapplications_jsp:410)
```

Does any one know how to fix this?

I mean, Liferay can work normally as usual, as in the myliferay on localhost.
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: that is odd. you need to go through some troubleshooting there, make sure the bundle is reliable, if you use exotic sources, then double check your permission system to make sure tomcat can access the libs, also if you are coming from GA5, make sure you go through the proper upgrade procedure.

Comment: You can also try docker, and avoid those issues: https://www.e-systems.tech/web/guest/liferay

Answer (score 0):

We faced this issue as well recently. Because of an unsatisfied reference, not all of GroupPagesPortlet's services started. In our case, there were an entry in the release_ table which state_ was not 0, it was 1. Value 1 means a failed upgrade.

In our case the workaround/solution was to change the value to 0 then restart the server.

In more details:

1) Connected to Gogo shell

2) Ran scr:list
Found:
  [ 389]   com.liferay.layout.admin.web.internal.portlet.GroupPagesPortlet  enabled
    [2746] [unsatisfied reference]

3) Running scr:info on the component ID (2746 in the above output), it reported the following unsatisfied references:

```
UnsatisfiedReference: MDRActionLocalService
  Target: null
  (no target services)
UnsatisfiedReference: MDRActionService
  Target: null
  (no target services)
UnsatisfiedReference: MDRRuleGroupInstanceLocalService
  Target: null
  (no target services)
UnsatisfiedReference: MDRRuleGroupInstanceService
  Target: null
  (no target services)
```

4) Ran dm wtf and it reported that com.liferay.mobile.device.rules.service doesn't have a proper release state, or is at the wrong version:

- com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.Release (&(release.bundle.symbolic.name=com.liferay.mobile.device.rules.service)(&(release.schema.version>=1.0.0)(!(release.schema.version>=1.1.0)))(|(!(release.state=*))(release.state=0))) is not found in the service registry

So to summarize, com.liferay.mobile.device.rules.service failed to upgrade, which resulted in all of its transitive dependencies failing to start. GroupPagesPortlet happens to be one of those dependencies.